# SQL Query to find string that follows a particular pattern

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-like

I have a varchar column in a table and I need to find all values in the column that matches a pattern. The pattern is either **parta-partb-partc** or **parta-partb-positiveInteger-partc**. Except for the number part, everything is fixed. 
For example

```
**someColumn**

parta-partb-partc
parta-partb-1-partc
parta-partb-1xyz-partc
parta-partb-123-partc
parta-partb-abc-partc
```

My search query should return

```
parta-partb-partc
parta-partb-1-partc
parta-partb-123-partc
```

So far this is what I got

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM tableName 
 WHERE 
      someColumn ='parta-partb-partc' 
   OR someColumn LIKE 'parta-partb-%[0-9]-partc'
```

I am not able to construct the LIKE part to get only strings with positive number in between.

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: hsqlserver for testing but could any among sqlserver, oracle or mysql in production

Comment: Function would differ according to the database. If you could suggest a right database, can provide you the solution

Comment: I can't be sure what database the customer might use. What do you suggest in this case? Should I bring in the values through someColumn LIKE 'parta-partb-%-partc' and use java regular expression to filter out the none required ones?

Answer (score 1):

For MySQL following query gives expected result

```
SELECT *
FROM
  tableName
WHERE
   someColumn = 'parta-partb-partc'
   OR 
   someColumn REGEXP 'parta-partb-[0-9]+-partc'
;
```

For Oracle following query gives expected result

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
WHERE
   someColumn = 'parta-partb-partc'
   OR 
   REGEXP_LIKE(someColumn, 'parta-partb-[[:digit:]]+-partc')
;
```

For MS-SQL unfortunately REGEX is not supported in where clause, so you have to do something like following. [Specific to your example data]

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
WHERE
   someColumn = 'parta-partb-partc'
   OR 
   (    someColumn LIKE 'parta-partb-[0-9]-partc'
    OR  someColumn LIKE 'parta-partb-[0-9]%[0-9]-partc'
    AND someColumn NOT LIKE 'parta-partb-[0-9]%[a-zA-Z]%[0-9]-partc'
    AND someColumn NOT LIKE 'parta-partb-[0-9]%[a-zA-Z]-partc'
   )
```